Should I plan for potential current capacity demands when sizing a circuit?
I have a 15 amp circuit that, once upon a time, ran 8 overhead lights.  Each was a single socket that accommodated a 60-100 watt incandescent bulb.  That would be 800 watts, or 7 amps total if all were on at once.  Nowadays all those bulbs are LEDs that use maybe 15 watts power, about 1 amp maximum (total).  If my rough match is correct.
If I have a new sump pump going in that requires 4 amps, that should be OK on the same circuit, right?
Do I need to save "room" in a load calculation for the possibility that someone might later use high wattage bulbs where I now have LEDs?

Your question isn't really about light bulbs. It could be anything plugged into a circuit that raises current draw in the future. I've revised your title. Feel free to revise further.

If you ever decide to install a small generator, ie any one that is not "whole house", you'll want to ration power to the sump pump and other moderate loads while ignoring small but critical loads like LED lights.
What you want in particular is to use the breaker panel to disable pumps, waste disposal, garage door, fridges, and other motors and to enable them selectively as needed. You would normally leave the fridges on and not the sumps.  And just leave lights, Internet, and other small things on all the time.
For that reason, do not combine them.

For many people, a working sump pump is a critical load and failure could cause serious and expensive damage.

@PhilipNgai true.   But if your sumps run continuously you'll need and already have one would hope, a much better solution than a small generator with manual switching.

Unplugging the sump would work, too.  It is corded

@nuggethead If you have two sump pumps, two fridges, two garage door openers, a waste disposal, and IDK maybe more motors or high loads, managing this by unplugging things is harder.   Remember, OP is thinking ahead and planning, hence my advice.  If the question was how to manage an existing installation where things were combined, the advice would be different.

@jay613 good call.  Also things like sumps come on when they need to and it would be easy to forget it was on

7 + 4 = 11 amps.  This is never a problem on a 15 amp circuit.  Sump pumps are not a continuous load in normal situations.  If you treat the pump as a fastened motor for load calculation, it's still only 5 amps.
The more important consideration is the requirement for GFCI.

Incandescent bulbs are no longer sold in the US, so the concern about higher wattage bulbs is minimal. If someone should find some incandescents and install them, in the worst case the breaker will trip, alerting the user to replace the high wattage bulbs with LEDs.

Why would 7 Amps of incandescent lights trip a 15 Amp circuit breaker?
